# Webdriver: How to click on a button for a specific row of a table (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, dynamic, webdriver

[image: table data]

Hi,

The table shown in the picture is dynamic. The test case is to click on the respective Delete button where the name is equal to "Test Group 2".

Please suggest C# code.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML as text, not a picture.

Comment: try something like  `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table#assetGroup-table tr:nth-child(2)  td:nth-child(4) img:nth-child(2)"));`

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing what is under that fourth td I can't say for sure, but you can find it with an xpath that looks something like this.

```
//td[contains(text(),'Test Group 2')]/..//td[4]//button
```

You might have to specify which button since that edit button will be in the same td.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method. Pass the value for what you are looking for like "Test Group 2". The below will loop through the table and stop on the value. From there, pass in the below to click the trash can.

```
 tds[i + 4].Click();
```

So look at the columns and just count to the right (+) or left (-). If you wanted to click the assign button it should be:

```
tds[i + 2].Click();
```

If you had a button to the left of "Test Group 2" you would pass in:

```
tds[i - 1].Click();
```

Method:

```
 public void ClickTableLink(string value)
 {
 var table =  driver.FindElement(By.Id("assetGroup-table"));
 foreach (var tr in table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")))
 {
 var tds = tr.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
for (var i = 0; i < tds.Count; i++)
{
    if (tds[i].Text.Trim().Contains(value))
    {
        tds[i + 4].Click();
        break;
    }

   }
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to know. What data type of variable table, tr, and tds?

Comment: table is the locator of the table. tr is table row and td is just the cell. These are just strings. This looks at the table > grabs the table rows> then grabs teh cell values. Once you have that, it loops through the table and looks for your cell value and it stops.  From there you can move left or right to interact with that row,