# Selenium C# List Elements between Xpaths

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was wondering if this is capable/ anyone has an example.

The webpage I'm accessing has a very structured layout and uses comments to start and finish sections.

In each section their is always a opening comment, a closing comments and a `<h3></h3>` and then only sometimes a `<table></table>`

If I know the Xpaths where a section starts and where it finishes is there a way to loop this range?

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Asset Allocation -->
<h3 style="border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC; margin-top: 20px;">Asset Allocation</h3>
<p class="fundreportsubheading">% as at 31 Aug 2017</p>
<table class="table2 tablefundreport noth">
                <tbody><tr class="N_Qodd">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Domestic Equity</td>
                    <td>4.181</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="N_Qeven">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">International Equity</td>
                    <td>95.494</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="N_Qodd">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Listed Property</td>
                    <td>0.000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="N_Qeven">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Unlisted Property</td>
                    <td>0.000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="N_Qodd">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Domestic Fixed Interest</td>
                    <td>0.000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="N_Qeven">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">International Fixed Interest</td>
                    <td>0.000</td>
                </tr>
               
                <tr class="N_Qodd">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Cash</td>
                    <td>0.325</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="N_Qeven">
                    <td style="text-align: left; border-bottom: none;">Other</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom: none;">0.000</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody></table>
<!-- /Asset Allocation -->
```

**Sample comment Xpaths**

```
            //*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[3]/comment()[3]
            //*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[3]/comment()[4]
```

Comment: Which _Selenium Binding Art_ are you using _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_?

Comment: C# but happy to use python if need

Comment: The question is not really clear to me. What range do you want to loop here? All the <h3>, <p> and <table>, only a few of them, or something else? Does the section have a tag of his own, i.e. a <div> that contains all these elements?

Comment: I am not following you 100% either but if you want to loop through a table, you can. Then you can run asserts on values or click on rows in a table. I added an example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853855/webdriver-how-to-click-on-a-button-for-a-specific-row-of-a-table-c/43859473#43859473 for doing a click.

Comment: Sorry about clarity. I’m trying to loop the element range between the comments. There are multiple section on the page structured like this and I want to associate the header with the table, however sometimes there isn’t always a table